I can't figure out what I am doing wrong with firebase on my website
I am making a site where someone can send a link to there phone which will open after a set amount of time (the part on the phones end works already), but I feel like I have tried nearly everything to be able to enter my data into the firestore/realtime database but I always get one of the following errors: (test is the name of my function as I am using it to test how it works)
Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: doc is not defined
index.js (the config is filled in properly, just left it out here)
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";
import { getFirestore, doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  /* config */
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = getDatabase();
const firestore = getFirestore(app);

html script tag and function call (put beneath eachother for ease of reading)
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
<div class=inputsDiv><input type="submit" id="submitLinks" name="submitLinks" onclick=test()></div>

test function in my scripts.js file
async function test() {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const myId = urlParams.get('id');
  
    var input = document.getElementById("slink").value;
  
    if (!(input.startsWith("https://") || input.startsWith("http://"))) {
        input = "http://" + input
    }
  
    console.log("attempting to send " + input + " to " + myId)
    
    const docRef = doc(firestore, "links", myId)
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
  
    if (docSnap.exists()) {
        console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
        
        const userId = docSnap.data().uid
  
        set(ref(db, 'users/' + userId), {
            link: input
          });
      } else {
        // docSnap.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
  }

I also tried importing the data in my scripts.js file, however this lead to the function not being found anymore by the onClick method (even when changing the script type to "module")

How are you importing or including index.js?

I tried importing it in the function itself using import("../src/index.js"), but this did not seem to help at all as I got this error:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module
I also tried importing it outside of the function with: import { app, firestore, database} from "../src/index.js" but this resulted in a not found error.

If you're not adding that file to the page, it's definitely not going to run or work the way you expect.  I suggest reviewing the documentation on your options for including it into your project.  There are a lot of options, and you have to pick the right one for the framework or module system you're using.

I think I understand it a bit more now, the only thing I am not sure about is if it is fine if the user could see the firebase config, because if it is would it be a problem if I place the code directly in the index.js file?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public

Thank you very much for your  help! I figured out how to make it work!
